# link to iPad app in appstore from an iPhone version

Tags: iphone, ipad, hyperlink, app-store

I can't seem to get this to work. I can link to other iphone apps in appstore and they will take the user to the appstore. But iPad links do not seem to work? Has anyone managed to get a working link to an iPad app in appstore?

Answer (score 2):

The iPad store (and its products) is not available on the iPhone - which is a good thing as people would quickly become frustrated after buying apps that don't work on their devices.

If you open the link on the iPad it will work, as it is just a plain URL opened with Safari. Just no way to show pure iPad apps on the integrated AppStore on iPhone devices.